# Spark on Mesos: tasks get scheduled on a single node

Tags: apache-spark, scheduling, mesos

Suppose I'm running a pyspark shell against a Mesos cluster. I'd like to occupy just 12 CPU cores. So I launch it like this:

```
uu@r4:~$ pyspark --master mesos://e3.test:5050 --total-executor-cores 12
```

And then goes the usual stuff:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.2
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: uu
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: uu
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(uu); users with modify permissions: Set(uu)
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53336.
17/01/31 08:16:31 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@r4.test:59860]
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 59860.
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /var/tmp/spark/blockmgr-6b16ff11-b0bc-4a71-82f5-c69a363c8c1a
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://r4.test:4040
I0131 08:16:32.582038 24965 sched.cpp:226] Version: 1.1.0
I0131 08:16:32.586931 24958 sched.cpp:330] New master detected at master@192.168.0.15:5050
I0131 08:16:32.587162 24958 sched.cpp:341] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0131 08:16:32.596922 24956 sched.cpp:743] Framework registered with 075ef8d0-de21-472d-8198-80805006b93d-0051
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Registered as framework ID 075ef8d0-de21-472d-8198-80805006b93d-0051
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 51135.
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 51135
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager r4.test:51135 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, r4.test, 51135)
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
17/01/31 08:16:32 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 0 is now TASK_RUNNING
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.2
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Dec 20 2016 23:09:15)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
```

but it ends up with only one executor registered:

```
>>> 17/01/31 08:16:35 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (r5.test:42965) with ID 023af0f2-fc60-4d9d-a3db-301ab34764c9-S3
17/01/31 08:16:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager r5.test:33239 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(023af0f2-fc60-4d9d-a3db-301ab34764c9-S3, r5.test, 33239)
```

meaning that the whole Spark app is about to run on the single node. And this is not the scheduling I want (primarily due to data locality considerations). What I was expecting is more like Spark standalone setup way: `--total-executor-cores` spread more or less evenly across the cluster.

Any way to achieve this? Remaining options mentioning executors/cores numbers do not seem to have any effect (and are related to standalone and Yarn configurations only).

Why exactly does Spark with Mesos employ this placement strategy of filling up nodes one by one rather than distributing work?

UPD: Conf entries mentioned in the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#coarse-grained) do not work either:

```
pyspark --master mesos://e3.test:5050 --conf spark.executor.cores=2 --conf spark.cores.max=12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version 1.6.2
```

is the problem. In the more recent versions there is an option `spark.cores.max` capping the number of cores per executor.